# "localhost didn't send any data" when using Golang + Gin + Docker

Tags: docker, go, containers

I've created a simple API following a youtube tutorial that works perfectly locally. Once I containerise the app and run the container, I can't access the API at http://localhost:8080. I'm guessing it has something to do with the port settings I'm using in the dockerfile, but I'm not sure.

main.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "errors"
)

type phone struct{
    ID       string `json:"id"`
    Model    string `json:"model"`
    Year     string `json:"year"`
    Quantity int    `json:"quantity"`
}

var phones = []phone{
    {ID: "1", Model: "iPhone 11", Year: "2019", Quantity: 4},
    {ID: "2", Model: "iPhone 6", Year: "2014", Quantity: 9},
    {ID: "3", Model: "iPhone X", Year: "2017", Quantity: 2},
}

func phoneById(c *gin.Context) {
    id := c.Param("id")
    phone, err := getPhoneById(id)

    if err != nil {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Phone not found."})
        return
    }

    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, phone)
}

func checkoutPhone(c *gin.Context) {
    id, ok := c.GetQuery("id")

    if !ok {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"Message": "Missing id query paramater"})
        return
    }

    phone, err := getPhoneById(id)

    if err != nil {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"Message": "Phone not found"})
        return
    }

    if phone.Quantity <= 0 {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"Message": "Phone not available."})
        return
    }

    phone.Quantity -= 1
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, phone)
}

func returnPhone(c *gin.Context) {
    id, ok := c.GetQuery("id")

    if !ok {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"Message": "Missing id query paramater"})
        return
    }

    phone, err := getPhoneById(id)

    if err != nil {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"Message": "Phone not found"})
        return
    }

    if phone.Quantity <= 0 {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"Message": "Phone not available."})
        return
    }

    phone.Quantity += 1
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, phone)
}

func getPhoneById(id string) (*phone, error) {
    for i, p := range phones {
        if p.ID == id {
            return &phones[i], nil
        }
    }

    return nil, errors.New("Phone not found.")
}


func getPhones(c *gin.Context) {
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, phones)
}

func createPhone(c *gin.Context) {
    var newPhone phone

    if err := c.BindJSON(&newPhone); err != nil {
        return 
    }

    phones = append(phones, newPhone)
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusCreated, newPhone)
}

func main(){
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/phones", getPhones)
    router.GET("/phones/:id", phoneById)
    router.POST("/phones", createPhone)
    router.PATCH("/checkout", checkoutPhone)
    router.PATCH("/return", returnPhone)
    router.Run("localhost:8080")
}
```

and my dockerfile:

```
#The standard golang image contains all of the resources to build
#But is very large.  So build on it, then copy the output to the
#final runtime container
FROM golang:latest AS buildContainer
WORKDIR /go/src/app

COPY . .

#flags: -s -w to remove symbol table and debug info
#CGO_ENALBED=0 is required for the code to run properly when copied alpine
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -mod mod -ldflags "-s -w" -o restapi .

#Now build the runtime container, just a stripped down linux and copy the
#binary to it.
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=buildContainer /go/src/app/restapi .

ENV GIN_MODE release

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./restapi"]
```

I've tried different dockerfiles found on Google, and tried creating my own from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind to the public network interface inside the container. Because each container is its own host, and when you bind to the loopback interface inside, it will not be accessible to the outside world.

```
router.Run("0.0.0.0:8080")
```

Additionally, make sure you publish this port when running the container.

```
docker run --publish 8080:8080 myapp
```

You actually indicate the right intend with your environment variables, but they are not used in your code.

```
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV PORT 8080
```

You can use [os.Getenv](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv) or [os.LookupEnv](https://pkg.go.dev/os#LookupEnv) to get those variables from your code and use them.

Comment: The container runs as usual but I still can't access 0.0.0.0:8080 or localhost:8080

Comment: how did you start the container? And what have you added to th router.Run method?

Comment: I used "docker run --publish 8080:8080 hello" to start the container. And changed router.Run("localhost:8080") to router.Run("0.0.0.0:8080"), still works locally but can't access in the container.

Comment: you have anything in the logs? Its the program actually running ok inside the container?

Comment: Well. I've noticed that I don't get any message back in the terminal to say it's running anymore after the command is entered. It just shows the command and the "[]" line below to symbolize something is happening.. however on Docker Desktop it says the container is running. Logs does not load at all.

Comment: I think gin does usually some logging by default. Can you try to build the image without the second stage. It can be tricky to compile go for alpine properly, although then I would expect an error message from the container. I would still give it a shot. And to be sure add some log statement at the top of your main function, so you can see if its starting at all.

Comment: @MantleLoL, you could also try to set GIN_MODE to debug and see if you get more info.

Comment: I reverted to an old dockerfile, following the official docs at https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/. This didn't work before. But following your advice and changing localhost:8080 in my application source code to 0.0.0.0:8080 fixed the issue. Seemed like a dockerfile + source code problem. Thanks.

Comment: @MantleLoL, yes thats a good way if you do what is described further down, using [distroless](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/#multi-stage-builds). I am using those too to run my go binaries. I usually use `gcr.io/distroless/static:nonroot` though. But then you need to run go build to cgo disabled.